# How to retrive domain account hashes from windows 2008 server?

Tags: audit

I want to do password length audit of domain password using offline brute force analysis.
I cannot find any domain hashes from local machines , I want an approach where i can retrieve these hashes either though AD database file or by running some hashing retrieval tool.

Can someone please guide me how could this be done? I'm using l0phtcrack as password auditing tool.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's explained in the l0phtcrack documentation.

http://www.l0phtcrack.com/help/using.html#obtaining_hashes

Your options for obtaining the hashes are:

- Import From Local Machine in l0phtcrack
- Import From Remote Machine in l0phtcrack
- Manually copying the SAM file and uploading it (no good in Windows 2008)
- Importing the results of running PWDUMP3
- Sniffing network login attempts

So, assuming you have sufficient privileges, you should be able to grab the hashes directly from the l0phtcrack application.

Comment: Lovely. +1 from me